# Why does this follow from the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

*This is a lemma in the classical book Brownian Motion and Stochastic calculus by Karatzas and Shreve. It is on page 133.*

> He makes an assertion that a set has Lebesgue measure 0, and that this
>   follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus. But why is this?
>   Isn't the fundamental theorem of calculus something that deals with
>   Riemann integration? We are working with Lebesgue integrals.
>
> The problem is showing that for fixed $\omega$, the lebegsue measure
>   of t's where $\widetilde{X}^{(m)}(t,\omega)$ converges to
>   $X(t,\omega)$ is 0. But since we have an m in the integrand which
>   makes up $\widetilde{X}^{(m)}(t,\omega)$ I can not see that we can use
>   the DCT directly, because it is not bounded. So it seems like he does
>   something with the fundamental theorem of calculus instead?

**It is a long proof, I put up everything here. But I highlighted what is relevant for the question in green, and the thing I do not know in red. Do you see how he can say what he says?**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says that, for fixed $\omega$, the function 
$$F_t(\omega) = \int_0^{t\wedge T}X_s(\omega) ds$$ is  absolutely continuous with respect to $t$, and $\frac{dF_t(\omega)}{dt} = X_t(\omega)$ almost everywhere over the interval $[0, \, T]$. That is, almost everywhere,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\widetilde{X}_t^m(\omega) &= \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} m\left(F_t(\omega) - F_{(t-1/m)^+}(\omega) \right) = X_t(\omega).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $A_{\omega}$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Thank you very much!, I totally forgot that there was a version of this theorem connected to the Lebesgue-integrals.